# how to get all weeks in january to december in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get 1st week to 52 weeks in the year in SQL query.
I try using datepaert ,datediff functions in SQL.
what can I use for it and how to get all weeks from the whole year

I try using this query

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, activity_detail.created_date) AS week,
COUNT(activity_detail.activity_type_config_id) As count,
user_det.full_name
FROM activity_detail activity_detail,activity_type_config activity_type_config,activity_user user_det 
WHERE activity_detail.activity_type_config_id = activity_type_config.activity_type_config_id and user_det.activity_user_id = activity_detail.activity_user_id
AND activity_detail.created_date BETWEEN '2021-01-08' AND '2021-11-17' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, activity_detail.created_date),user_det.full_name
ORDER BY DATEPART(week, activity_detail.created_date)
```

output

```
week|count|name
41  11  john
41  67  carter
41  885 rapit
```

this query was executed output is only database week, I need to get all weeks in a year.

I need like this output

```
week|count|name
1   0   null
2   0   null
3   0   null
4   0   null ...
41  67  carter
41  885 rapit
51  0   null
52  0   null
```

please help me

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  `SELECT version();`

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL?  If not, adjust the question tags.  SQL Server supports datepart.  MySQL may not have this natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MySQL 8.0 or better, we can use recursion to generate the week numbers.
There are other ways to do this for prior versions.

```
WITH RECURSIVE weeks (n) AS (
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM weeks WHERE n < 52
     )
SELECT w.*, t.*
  FROM      weeks AS w
  LEFT JOIN test  AS t
    ON w.n = WEEK(t.sdate)
   AND t.sdate < '2022-01-01'
 WHERE w.n > 35             -- Check just the last few weeks of this year.
 ORDER BY n
;
```

**Setup (to provide a few weeks of data):**

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id  int primary key auto_increment, sdate DATE );

INSERT INTO test (sdate) VALUES
  (current_date - INTERVAL    '2' WEEK)
, (current_date - INTERVAL  0*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  1*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  2*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  3*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  4*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  5*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  6*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  7*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  8*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL  9*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL 10*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL 11*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL 12*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL 13*'2' WEEK)
, (current_date + INTERVAL 14*'2' WEEK)
;
```

**The result:**

```
+------+------+------------+
| n    | id   | sdate      |
+------+------+------------+
|   36 | NULL | NULL       |
|   37 | NULL | NULL       |
|   38 |    1 | 2021-09-21 |
|   39 | NULL | NULL       |
|   40 |    2 | 2021-10-05 |
|   41 | NULL | NULL       |
|   42 |    3 | 2021-10-19 |
|   43 | NULL | NULL       |
|   44 |    4 | 2021-11-02 |
|   45 | NULL | NULL       |
|   46 |    5 | 2021-11-16 |
|   47 | NULL | NULL       |
|   48 |    6 | 2021-11-30 |
|   49 | NULL | NULL       |
|   50 |    7 | 2021-12-14 |
|   51 | NULL | NULL       |
|   52 |    8 | 2021-12-28 |
+------+------+------------+
```

**Test case for SQL Server:**

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id  int identity, sdate DATE );

INSERT INTO test (sdate) VALUES
  (DATEADD(week,  2, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week, 22, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week,  4, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week,  6, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week,  7, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week,  9, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week, 11, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week, 13, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week, 12, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week, 15, getdate()))
, (DATEADD(week, 16, getdate()))
;

WITH weeks (n) AS (
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM weeks WHERE n < 53
     )
SELECT w.*, t.*
  FROM      weeks AS w
  LEFT JOIN test  AS t
    ON w.n = DATEPART(week, t.sdate)
   AND t.sdate < '2022-01-01'
 WHERE w.n > 40
 ORDER BY n
;
```

**The Result:**

[image]